# set location of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring ApplicationContext relative to applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file, applicationcontext

I would like to know: Is it possible to set the location of a property-file for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in the spring applicationContext.xml relative to the xml-file itself?

So when applicationContext.xml and dataSource.properties files are in the same directory:
will something like this work, or wouldn't Spring find the file, because i have to modify the location-property value?

```
<bean id="dataSourceProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="location" value="dataSource.properties" />   
</bean>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you test it and did it work? It should.

Comment: Now i did - it doesn't: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: dataSource.properties (No such file or directory) at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
So I wonder how to resolve this problem as easy as possible :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No this will not work.

The "value" for the location will not start with the location of applicationContext.xml as "root-directory". It will use the directory from where the spring application was started.

Maybe anyone other will have this question too :P

Answer (score 2):

Put your `dataSourceProperties.properties` file in the `resources` folder, modify your `dataSourceProperties` bean as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSourceProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:dataSource.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And get the property out of it in your class definition as follows:

```
@WebService
@Component
public class MyService{

      @Value("${databaseDriver}")
      private String databaseDriver;

      ....

}
```

Moreover, get complete property file, as follows:

```
 @Component
 public class MyService{

     @Resource(name="dataSourceProperties")
     private Properties dataSourceProperties;

     ....

 }
```

**dataSource.properties:**

```
databaseDriver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```